# Dúvidas relacionadas a um sistema de anti cheat

Tags: c++, c++11

Não encontrei um meio melhor de descrever o título do tópico, se não estiver bom o bastante, peço que a moderação edite-o para mim.

Tenho algumas dúvidas relacionadas a um sistema de anti cheat eficaz para jogos. Sim, eu sei que o melhor anti cheat vem diretamente do servidor do jogo, porém, tenho a necessidade de criar um que seja feito diretamente para o cliente do jogo.

Pergunta: *Quais seriam as melhores escolhas que eu poderia tomar para iniciar esse projeto, visando não prejudicar (ou o mínimo possível) o desempenho do jogo?*

Pensei em um sistema de verificação de processos constante, e então me surgiram dúvidas em relação a ele, como:

1. É possível impedir que outros programas forcem o encerramento ou congelamento de uma thread?
2. Existe uma maneira de saber se uma thread está congelada?
3. Um sistema de cache para impedir que os mesmos processos sejam verificados novamente seria uma boa escolha? Penso, seria possível um programa que já foi verificado e não é detectado como uma ameaça de acordo com os 'dumps' salvos no banco de dados, passar por alguma mudança e tornar-se uma ameaça?
4. Seria possível criar um "whitelist" de exe's/dll's que podem acessar/alterar a memória de um determinado programa e bloquear os demais não listados?
5. Criar uma dll para o executável do jogo com verificações leves e um executável separado com as verificações mais pesadas, beneficiam em algo ou seria a mesma coisa que estivesse tudo (verificações leves e pesadas) na dll junto com o executável do jogo?
6. Sugestões?

Comment: Acredito que para ajudar em termos de performance precisaríamos saber um pouco mais da estrutura do seu projeto. Dá uma olhada nesse [repo](https://github.com/SLAUC91/AntiCheat).

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário. Em relação a estrutura do projeto, ainda não tenho nada. Estou colhendo informações e conhecimentos de todos que estejam dispostos a ajudar, para que eu possa aplicar no meu novo projeto. Em relação a performance, foi apenas um pequeno detalhe que eu quis ressaltar, porque eu sempre escolho caminhos mais "difíceis" que futuramente acabam prejudicando o projeto. Então, foi mais para receber dicas de quem tem mais conhecimento que eu, pois quanto menos eu interferir no desempenho do jogo, melhor para o meu projeto, desde que mantenha o jogo seguro contra trapaças.

Comment: O seu 4 ponto já é feito em alguns jogos que simplesmente fecham se determinados executáveis tiverem a correr. Corresponde neste caso uma blacklist de exe's

Comment: Qual a arquitetura do seu jogo? Stand alone no computador? Multiplayer em LAN? Multiplayer via internet? Já tem noção se vai ser ação ou estratégia?

Comment: É um MMORPG para Windows 32 bits.

Comment: O que muito eu vejo é uma solução de captcha. Vi muito disso no Ragnarok online, mas tive impressão de ter visto em outros também. Essa solução não é preventiva, mas visa garantir que em dado momento tem um humano interagindo.

Comment: O melhor em relação à performance é tentar por no lado cliente a validação, não no lado do servidor. Claro, isso tem algumas consequências, como só valer para o cliente que você disponibilizou, não serviria para caso alguém tivesse feito a engenharia reversa da API. Mas retirar peso do servidor é uma tarefa muito grata, o servidor agradece e, sendo uma validação não muito complexa, o cliente não sente muito

Comment: O uso de captcha para o jogo que estou baseando meu projeto é dispensável... 
A maior preocupação é com programas que impedem as verificações de segurança e alterações nos valores do jogo como, por exemplo, um acelerador de gráfico que deixe o jogador fique super veloz e tenha vantagens no PvP.